# The difference both reboot and poweroff of Linux by systemctl control

Tags: linux, reboot, systemctl, power-off

Both **reboot** and **poweroff** are mapped to `/bin/systemctl`, how does `systemctl` control shutdown and restart. When entering **reboot** or **poweroff**, how does `systemctl` get which command should be executed?

It looks like both **reboot** and **poweroff** are linked to `/bin/systemctl`

```
➜  /usr/bin file /usr/sbin/reboot
/usr/sbin/reboot: symbolic link to /bin/systemctl
➜  /usr/bin file /usr/sbin/poweroff 
/usr/sbin/poweroff: symbolic link to /bin/systemctl
➜  /usr/bin 
➜  /usr/bin 
➜  /usr/bin 
➜  /usr/bin uname -a
Linux mi-OptiPlex-7080 5.15.0-76-generic #83~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 21 20:23:31 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
➜  /usr/bin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how does systemctl control shutdown and restart

When a command is executed under Linux it receives parameters. There is a special, first or "zero" parameter, that is the name of the process executed. See `man execve`.

```
$ bash -c 'echo $0'
bash
$ strace bash -c 'echo $0' 2>&1 | grep exec
execve("/usr/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "echo $0"], 0x7fff48f3f1d0 /* 115 vars */) = 0
                                        ^^^^^^^ - argument 2
                                  ^^ - argument 1
                          ^^^^^ - argument 0
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -  process to execute
```

The C program that is systemctl just checks the "0"-th argument and compares the string. In pseudocode:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (strcmp(argv[0], "poweroff") == 0) {
        I_am_poweroff();
    else if (strcmp(argv[0], "reboot") == 0) {
        reboot();
    } etc...
}
```

In real code this happens here https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/main/src/systemctl/systemctl.c#L1083 :
. You may also be interested in `busybox` project.